# How to permute binary string so to minimize distance between them?

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation

I've got an array of weights, for example

```
[1, 0, 3, 5]
```

The distance between two strings is defined as a sum of weights for different bits, like this:

```
size_t distance(const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2, const std::vector<size_t>& weights) {
  size_t result = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < str1.size(); ++i) {
    if (str1[i] != str2.at(i))
      result += weights.at(i);
  }
  return result;
}
```

and starting string for example

```
'1101'
```

I need to generate permutations in the way that strings with lowest distance from the original one go first, like this:

```
'1001'  # changed bits: 2nd. Because it has lowest weight. Distance is 0
'0101'  # changed bits: 1st.                               Distance is 1
'0001'  # changed bits: 1st, 2nd.                          Distance is 1
'1011'  # changed bits: 2nd, 3rd.                          Distance is 3
'1111'  # changed bits: 3rd.                               Distance is 3
'0111'  # changed bits: 1st, 3rd.                          Distance is 4
'0011'  # changed bits: 1st, 2nd, 3rd.                     Distance is 4
'1100'  # changed bits: 4th.                               Distance is 5
'1000'  # changed bits: 2nd, 4th.                          Distance is 5
'0100'  # changed bits: 1st, 4th.                          Distance is 6
'0000'  # changed bits: 1st, 2nd, 4th.                     Distance is 6
'1110'  # changed bits: 3rd, 4th.                          Distance is 8
'1010'  # changed bits: 2nd, 3rd, 4th.                     Distance is 8
'0110'  # changed bits: 1st, 3nd, 4th.                     Distance is 9
'0010'  # changed bits: 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th.                Distance is 9
```

I don't need code, I need just an algorithm which gets string of length N, array of weights of the same length and i as input and generates i-th permutation, without generating the whole list and sorting it.

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work? The problem you are trying to solve isn't very clear

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I've tried to make it a little bit more clear

Comment: generates  array of weights for the same length. how?

Comment: Those aren't really permutations (permutations only change the order). To generate all four-character strings of `'0'` and `'1'`, convert the numbers from 0 to 15 to four binary digits.

Comment: @sajib I think OP only wants to calculate the permutation, both starting string and weights are input parameters.

Comment: @Soonts, yep, thanks

Comment: To generate permutations one can use `std::next_permutation`.

Comment: Your post remains very unclear: Do your strings only ever contain `0` and `1`? If so, why don't you use `bitset`s or `vector<bool>`? What is the meaning of a *starting string*? Where do the permutations come into play?

Comment: max length of N?

Comment: That sounds as if you wanted to sort all possible strings of above kind according to their distance from "1101". If so, you mentioning the term "permutation" is a bit of a red herring.

Comment: The starting string is irrelevant to the algorithm. You only need an algorithm that generates the _changes_ in the right order; then you can apply those changes to any starting string.

Answer (score 1):

In modern C++, the way to go about doing what you're asking is by using [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) to represent all possible bit *multiset*s and then wrapping `distance()` with a [*comparer* functor struct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) in order to call [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). I emphasize *possible bit [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)*, **not [*permutations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)**, as the latter only allow change of order. Your code then will look something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

constexpr size_t BITSET_SIZE = 4;

size_t distance(const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2, const std::array<size_t, BITSET_SIZE>& weights) {
    size_t result = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str1.size(); ++i) {
        if (str1[i] != str2.at(i))
            result += weights.at(i);
    }
    return result;
}

struct of_lesser_distance
{
    const std::bitset<BITSET_SIZE>& originalBitSet;
    const std::array<size_t, BITSET_SIZE>& distanceVec;

    inline bool operator() (const std::bitset<BITSET_SIZE>& lhs, const std::bitset<BITSET_SIZE>& rhs)
    {
        return distance(originalBitSet.to_string(), lhs.to_string(), distanceVec) < distance(originalBitSet.to_string(), rhs.to_string(), distanceVec);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string s{"1101"};    
    std::array<size_t, 4> weights{1, 0, 3, 5};

    int possibleBitSetsCount = std::pow(2, s.length());

    std::vector<std::bitset<BITSET_SIZE>> bitSets;

    // Generates all possible bitsets
    for (auto i = 0; i < possibleBitSetsCount; i++)
        bitSets.emplace_back(i);

    // Sort them according to distance
    std::sort(bitSets.begin(), bitSets.end(), of_lesser_distance{ std::bitset<BITSET_SIZE>(s), weights });

    // Print
    for (const auto& bitset : bitSets)
        std::cout << bitset.to_string().substr(BITSET_SIZE - s.length(), s.length()) << " Distance: " << distance(s, bitset.to_string(), weights) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1001 Distance: 0
1101 Distance: 0
0001 Distance: 1
0101 Distance: 1
1011 Distance: 3
1111 Distance: 3
0011 Distance: 4
0111 Distance: 4
1000 Distance: 5
1100 Distance: 5
0000 Distance: 6
0100 Distance: 6
1010 Distance: 8
1110 Distance: 8
0010 Distance: 9
0110 Distance: 9
```

Live version [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7amIRSqBi8cruHlA).

Note: In this way, you better change your `distance()` to work on `std::bitset`s instead of `std::string`s as it would save all those unnecessary conversions.

> I don't need code, I need just an algorithm

It's easier for me to give code but let me know if you wanted something else.

Comment: Not exactly, I wanted algorithm to give i-th string without generating whole list and sorting it.

Comment: @devalone I see now. The confusion arises from the fact that you didn't specify the non-generating, non-sorting requirement and the code answer was specifically C++ because of your tagging of the question with the C++ tag and the `distance()` snippet was C++...

Comment: Perhaps than this was a question for Computer Science stack exchange...

Comment: yes, I should specify it, and thanks for C++ way of representing bits

Comment: @devalone Ok glad to provide any help

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like hard problem.

If you are using size_t for permutation index, your strings will be limited to 32 or 64 characters, otherwise you’ll need larger integer for permutation index. Therefore, you can switch from strings to size_t bitmasks.

This way your algorithm no longer depends on the string, you find i-th bitmask, XOR it (`^` operator in C++) with the input string bitmask, and you get your result. The hard part is finding i-th bitmask but this way, i.e. without using strings in the inner loops of the algorithm, the code will be much faster (an orders of magnitude).

Now the hard part is how to find the mask. For general case, the only algorithm I can think of is extensive search, maybe with [memoisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) for performance. This will be fast for small permutation indices but slow for large ones.

If you know your weights at compile-time, you can precompute indices into a search tree but it’s best done outside C++, it’s very hard to use template metaprogramming for complex algorithms like this one.

P.S. There’s one special case that might work for you. Sort weights, and check whether the following is true `weights[N] == weights[N-1] || weights[N] >= sum( weights[0 .. N-1]` for all 1<N<length, you only need a single loop over the sorted weights to check that. If it’s true for all weights, and also all weights are non-negative, the solution is trivially simple, and the performance will be very fast, just treat index as a XOR bitmask. The only thing you need to do, reorder bits in the index to match the order of the weights array that was changed as the result of sorting them. For your weights, switch first and second bits because the sorted order is [0,1,3,5].

BTW, the weights you have in the question satisfy that condition, because 1>=0, 3>=0+1 and 5>=0+1+3, so this simple algorithm will work OK for your particular weights.

**Update:** here's a complete solution. It prints slightly different result than your sample, e.g. in your example you have '1011' then '1111' , my code will print '1011' immediately after '1111' but their distance is the same, i.e. my algorithm still works OK.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>

struct WeightWithBit
{
    size_t weight, bit;
};

// Sort the weights while preserving the original order in the separate field
std::vector<WeightWithBit> sortWeights( const std::vector<size_t>& weights )
{
    std::vector<WeightWithBit> sorted;
    sorted.resize( weights.size() );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < weights.size(); i++ )
    {
        sorted[ i ].weight = weights[ i ];
        sorted[ i ].bit = ( (size_t)1 << i );
    }
    std::sort( sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), []( const WeightWithBit& a, const WeightWithBit& b ) { return a.weight < b.weight; } );
    return sorted;
}

// Check if the simple bit-based algorithm will work with these weights
bool willFastAlgorithmWork( const std::vector<WeightWithBit>& sorted )
{
    size_t prev = 0, sum = 0;
    for( const auto& wb : sorted )
    {
        const size_t w = wb.weight;
        if( w == prev || w >= sum )
        {
            prev = w;
            sum += w;
            continue;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

size_t bitsFromString( const std::string& s )
{
    if( s.length() > sizeof( size_t ) * 8 )
        throw std::invalid_argument( "The string's too long, permutation index will overflow" );
    size_t result = 0;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ )
        if( s[ i ] != '0' )
            result |= ( (size_t)1 << i );
    return result;
}

std::string stringFromBits( size_t bits, size_t length )
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve( length );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < length; i++, bits = bits >> 1 )
        result += ( bits & 1 ) ? '1' : '0';
    return result;
}

// Calculate the permitation. Index is 0-based, 0 will return the original string without any changes.
std::string permitation( const std::string& str, const std::vector<WeightWithBit>& weights, size_t index )
{
    // Reorder the bits to get the bitmask.
    // BTW, if this function is called many times for the same weights, it's a good idea to extract just the ".bit" fields and put it into a separate vector, memory locality will be slightly better.
    size_t reordered = 0;
    for( size_t i = 0; index; i++, index = index >> 1 )
        if( index & 1 )
            reordered |= weights[ i ].bit;

    // Convert string into bits
    const size_t input = bitsFromString( str );
    // Calculate the result by flipping the bits in the input according to the mask.
    const size_t result = input ^ reordered;
    // Convert result to string
    return stringFromBits( result, str.length() );
}

int main()
{
    const std::vector<size_t> weights = { 1, 0, 3, 5 };

    using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
    const std::string theString = "1101"s;

    if( weights.size() != theString.length() )
    {
        printf( "Size mismatch" );
        return 1;
    }

    if( weights.size() > sizeof( size_t ) * 8 )
    {
        printf( "The string is too long" );
        return 1;
    }

    // Sort weights and check are they suitable for the fast algorithm
    const std::vector<WeightWithBit> sorted = sortWeights( weights );
    if( !willFastAlgorithmWork( sorted ) )
    {
        printf( "The weights aren't suitable for the fast algorithm" );
        return 1;
    }

    // Print all permutations
    const size_t maxIndex = ( 1 << weights.size() ) - 1;
    for( size_t i = 0; true; i++ )
    {
        const std::string p = permitation( theString, sorted, i );
        printf( "%zu: %s\n", i, p.c_str() );
        if( i == maxIndex )
            break;  // Avoid endless loop when the string is exactly 32 or 64 characters.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, but I don't completely understand why it works for this particular case

Answer (score 0):

This problem cannot be efficiently solved. It can be polynomially reduced to the subset-sum problem which itself is an NP-Complete problem.

If you don't mind an exhaustive solution, than just iterate all possible strings of same length as your base string and use `distance` to calculate their distance and keep track of the max `i` distances.

Original incorrect answer due to a misunderstanding of the question:
<s>Sounds like a simple problem. Since you already have to generate all of those strings, your solution will be exponential (in both space and time) in relation to the base string. You're basically unconstrained.</s>

You can try something like<sup>[1]</sup>:
 1. Generate all possible strings of same length as base string. 
It's rather simple. Just loop from 0 to (2<sup>|base_str|</sup>-1), and use `sprintf(&strs[loop_counter]"%b", loop_counter)`
 2. sort `strs` using `qsort` and use `distance` as the comperator. Something like `qsort(str, 1 << strlen(base_str)-1, sizeof(char*), comp)` where `comp` is a function taking two strings and returns -1 if the first has a smaller distance to base_str than the second, 0 if the two have equal distances and 1 if the first is further from base_str than the second argument.

<sup>[1]</sup>I'm a C, not C++, programmer so I'm sure there are other (perhaps better) ways to do what I suggest in C++, but my examples are in C.

Comment: You didn't get it, I need an algorithm to get n-th string from the list, not the whole list. Something like `std::string getPermutation(const std::string& original, const std::vector<size_t>& weights, size_t n);`

Comment: Oh, that's a much more interesting question. I'll try and see if I find any insights. If I won't, I'll just delete this answer.

Comment: @Neowizard “This problem cannot be efficiently solved” Sometimes it can. Check my answer for very fast method that works with the OP’s weights.

Comment: The condition you propose is very constraining. I don't think it applies to a large enough portion of the domain.
Basically, it requires the list of weights to be lower bound by a geometric series (ignoring elements equal to their predecessor).

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the ith permutation, then you only really need to look at the weights.

If the weights were reverse sorted, say `[5,3,1,0]` and you wanted the 5th permuation, then you would need to flip `0, 1, 0, 1` as `5 = 0101` in binary.

So you need a very small mapping from the weight to it's original index. Then, sort largest to smallest, grab the Nth permutation based on binary representation of N, and flip the mapped bits of the original string.

Comment: “grab the Nth permutation based on binary representation of N” weights are [4, 5, 6], binary representation will return distance 4+5=9 before 6. This only works for some weights (e.g. works OK for [1, 0, 3, 5]), see my answer for implementation.

Comment: @soonts you are correct, I didn't think about that. Works for prime number weights only.